# My angular project .war don't deploy in Tomcat/Payara Server

Tags: angular, maven, tomcat, deployment, glassfish

I use Payara Server for this proyect (Is similar to Glassfish I think). I need to add a frontEnd in my maven project and deploy the war in that Server. Since it didn't work, I tried it in Tomcat but I got the same result.

I follow the next steps for Payara:

1. I put in angular package.json "build":

   "ng build --prod --base-href= ./"

(the truth is that I have tried many routes trying to make this work for example y replace the . for  my war name or add a "/" at the final).

2. The result dist is: dist/Georreferenciacion/ I only  copy  the content inside Georreferenciacion.
   (Georreferenciacion is the name of my angular project),
3. I pull all inside of: **paginacion\src\main\resources\static** (paginacion is the name of the maven project)
4. I use the mvn comands: clean and package. The result is paginacion.war
5. I executed the payara server. In the admin module I deploy the result war.(I put a imagen at the end)
6. In my route  my angular project is supposed to appear, in the route:  **http://localhost:8080/paginacion/**  but it only reads the index.html without executing the scripts. The war don't have errors, because the APIS in the maven project works good.

In Tomcat are the same steps, and the same problem. The different is I upload all in **\src\main\webapp**

In both cases the error in the console is:

```
     GET http://localhost:8080/runtime.b9c754ff026a3181.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
paginacion/:13 
       GET http://localhost:8080/main.a3e20b2c30df8309.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
paginacion/:13 
       GET http://localhost:8080/polyfills.a04e0f6c8019e826.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
paginacion/:10 
       GET http://localhost:8080/styles.87eeefc8291f116b.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

The index.html in my angular project is the next:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PgoReepClienteWeb</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I watch the next tutorial video: https://youtu.be/Gkkj3qMn2yE?si=ISVpL4IPe29qcvlN

[image: War deploy in Payara Server]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I get the solution.

I put the name of the war in the "base href", inside index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PgoReepClienteWeb</title>
  <base href="/paginacion/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Also I put the next href:

"ng build --prod --base-href /paginacion/"